# Publishing Custom facebook actions on behalf of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, get, custom-action, facebook-page

I am trying to publish actions on behalf of a facebook page I administer via an app with the manage_pages permission. I am able to publish an action via a graph post of the folloing form:

```
<pageID>/<appNameSpace>:<actionName>?<objectName>=<objectURL>
```

But if I then query the app for published actions via the following call:

```
<pageID><appNameSpace>:<actionName>?access_token=<PageAccessToekn>
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
   }
}
```

Update:

If I attempt to publish using the following URL:

```
<pageID>/<appNameSpace>:<actionName>?<objectName>=<objectURL>&access_token=<pageToken>
```

If get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The Action Type <appNameSpace>:<actionName> is not approved, so app <appID> can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User <pageID> is not one of those roles.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

The page I am attempting to post on behalf of is administered by an app admin. I don't see any where in the roles section of the facebook developer app where facebook pages can be added as admins. Is there any what to test this? Is it possible to publish a custom action on behalf of a page?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the error message you posted, your custom action has not yet been approved by Facebook for public use. As far as I know, pages cannot be added to the list of test users (including admins and developers), so you may need to have your custom action approved by Facebook before moving forward.

You can read more about the approval process at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/. Their approval overview is included below:

> Because the Open Graph lets you integrate your app directly into all parts of the Facebook experience simply by making one API call, we are introducing a lightweight review and approval process before your app can publish Open Graph actions to all users.
>
> This process is straightforward. As soon as your app begins using the Open Graph, all Open Graph activity will be immediately visible to the developers and testers of your app. This allows you to do end-to-end testing of your integration. Once that is complete, submit your actions via the Dev App for review. After we have verified that your use of the Open Graph meets our criteria, we will approve your app to publish your Open Graph actions to all Facebook users.

Comment: Do you think publishing custom actions on behalf of a page is possible for an approved action? Also once I get my action approved will that limit my ability to edit the action (i.e. add and remove properties)?

Comment: Yes, that should work once you have your custom action approved. Once you've gone through the process, report back on your experience and results.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you need to get your open graph actions approved before posting to the open graph. Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/ for more details. Also I would do a check whether you have the publish_actions permission before you publish because the user has the ability to remove this permission at any time after he has authorized the app. After you get the open graph action approved, you can certainly edit them but you will have to resubmit the action for approval before live users could see these changes. This process takes longer than the first approval so I would get the requirements sorted out first.

Comment: This is true for posting actions for a user, but OP is asking about actions for a Page, which is not a currently feature of the API

Answer (score 0):

Posting actions to or as a Page, Event, Group is not possible, nor is it possible to post actions to a friend's Timeline - only users can post actions, and only to their own Timelines.

See the [Open Graph Mechanics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#mechanics) part of the docs, it shows that **users** perform an **action** on an **object**. What you're trying to do is having a Page take an action -  that's not supported

Comment: A lot of people simply don’t seem to get this …